# Stability of a long running NodeJS app listening for data changes

Tags: node.js

I want to create a utility in NodeJS that listens to Firebase changes, like this:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var agentRef = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com");
agentRef.child('users').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

It will run as long as possible, ideally forever, running some routine when changes happen.

The question is, how reliable is it to run a NodeJS for days, months?

How can I track it's healthy and runs as should. If it hangs, how do I know? Is it a right way at all? Maybe I should listen for changes with some other tools then run NodeJS code when needed?

Comment: I am asking because I assume people had this issue in their work before so could give me a piece of advice about how to handle this problem.

Comment: node.js apps can definitely run for days/weeks/months/years. it all depends on whether or not it has bugs that result in memory leaks/resource troubles which is going to depend on the modules being used and the code interacting with said modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you meet 2 type of problems

1. Unhandled exception
2. Low / insufficient resources (memory, descriptors, ...)

The first one easily solved by process control systems, like http://supervisord.org/, or [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever). It's good approach to log exceptions and just re-run nodejs process again

Low memory problem can't be solved directly by node.js, so you need to monitor it. If you had memory leaks - at some point you get some serious problem with machine.

If you can't fix leaks with changing code - try to re-run node.js after some number of events

node.js itself pretty stable for long production running, monitor your resources and logs, then decide how to fix

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @KevinB. The Node.js binary is stable, maybe not like linux kernel but still rock solid, as long as you use one of the LTS releases. The point is, your code (and the code you require, in this case `firebase`, is bringing instabilities into the system.

As @vmkcom has already answered, that's outside of scope of *node.js* itself, like bad Java code is outside of JBoss or Tomcat app servers. And people have been monitoring app server behavior forever. In node.js case, it's likely the suggested `supervisor`, or `forever` or `pm2`. Or plain old linux tools if you're handy with `bash` and friends.

Another point I'd like to make is how resilient your app is to outages of not just memory, but things like network, services etc? Do you have code in place that will reconnect if Firebase becomes briefly unavailable? Do you know how will your app behave if the host machine runs out of disk space, unrelated to your app? Can you survive the [Chaos Monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Chaos-Monkey)?